# Why is the answered questions percent dropping so rapidly?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions, statistics

I use Raspberry Pi SE as my base site on SE and I always check the answered questions percentage on the sidebar, as well as the other numbers, just to get an idea of how the site is doing. I had noticed that the percent answered had risen to 82%.

However, over the last day that number has quite dropped quite quickly, compared to the usual rate of change which is usually 1 percent changes over several days. I had noticed that it had dropped to 79% earlier today and posted something about noticing this in chat, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16127433#16127433.

A couple hours later I came on again, and noticed that it had dropped yet *another* percent to 78%, within ~2/3 hours of me last seeing the initial drop of 3% from 82% to 79%.

Now, I know that numbers aren't everything, and I know that the Q:A ratio isn't deathly important,  but I found this behaviour rather bizarre and I'm curious what might be causing it. Are there a lot of new questions that haven't been answered, or are answers being not considered as answered any more? Can any mods shed some light on this?

Comment: No idea, but as I have said before it is only a number and focusing on it has only resulted in negative behavior. Do what is right for the community and the rest will follow.

Comment: And I understand that focusing on numbers is bad. I was just curious what could be causing it.

Comment: I stopped answering questions because I was blocked from asking questions (On SO) Not sure if that has any relevance to your question though?